# lxml + django + uwsgi failed to generate a right format excel file？

Tags: python, django, excel, lxml, uwsgi

The excel file generated cannot be open when my project started with uwsgi when `lxml` installed in my environment as it can be opened successfully with `django manage.py runserver` and `gunicorn`

My main codes like below:

```
── test_excel
           ├── urls.py
           ├── wsgi.py
           └── settings.py

── manage.py
```

> urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.views import View
from openpyxl.writer.excel import save_virtual_workbook
import pandas as pd
from django.http import HttpResponse, StreamingHttpResponse


import xlrd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Alignment
from openpyxl.writer.excel import save_virtual_workbook
from openpyxl.cell.cell import ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS_RE



class TestExcelView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        # indexs = {0: ['cost', '2020-01', 'testing'],
        #           1: ['cost', '2020-01', '360 Limited'],
        #           2: ['cost', '2020-02', 'Korea Co.,LTD'],
        #           3: ['cost', '2020-02', 'ADS4EACH HK TECH LIMITED']}
        # columns = [['1'], ['amy'], ['tom'], ['zara'], ['jay'], ['Lee'], ['Uzi'], ['Zome'], ['Qoe'], ['Aoi'], ['Yeezy'],
        #            ['Hazy'], ['Wash'], ['pany'], ['zoey'], ['Moe'], ['total']]
        # datas = {
        #     0: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.85, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.85],
        #     1: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.85, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.85],
        #     2: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.85, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.85],
        #     3: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.85, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.85]
        # }
        #
        # index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(indexs.values())
        # column = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)
        # data = datas.values()
        #
        # df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=column)
        #
        # # 1 saved as excel
        #
        # excel_writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path='download.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
        # df.to_excel(excel_writer)
        # wb = excel_writer.book
        #
        # response = HttpResponse(save_virtual_workbook(wb))
        # response["Content-Type"] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
        # response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}.xlsx'.format("for_test")
        # return response

        wb = Workbook()
        ws = wb.active
        ws.merge_cells('A1:B1')
        a1 = ws["A1"]
        ws["A1"] = "reason"
        ws.column_dimensions["A"].width = 100
        ali = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center')

        a1.alignment = ali

        ws["A2"] = "request_id"
        ws.column_dimensions["A"].width = 50
        ws["B2"] = "rebate_reason"
        ws.column_dimensions["B"].width = 50

        for item in ws["A2:B2"][0]:
            item.font = Font(color='FF0000')
            item.alignment = ali

        response = HttpResponse(save_virtual_workbook(wb))
        response["Content-Type"] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}.xlsx'.format("test_excel")
        return response


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('test/', TestExcelView.as_view()),
]
```

> wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

#os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'test_excel.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

> test_excel.ini

```
[uwsgi]
pythonpath=/home/bluev/work/bv_crm_bak/test_excel
pythonpath=/home/bluev/work/bv_crm_bak/test_excel
env=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=test_excel.settings
module=test_excel.wsgi
master=True
pidfile=logs/test_excel.pid
vacuum=True
max-requests=100000
enable-threads=true
processes = 4
threads=8
listen=64
daemonize=logs/test_excel.log
log-slow=3000
python-autoreload=1
http=0.0.0.0:8876
```

Then if i start the project like `uwsgi --ini test_excel.ini` as `lxml` installed , and request `localhost:8876/test/`, i would get a failed excel file. But when I uninstalled `lxml` the result is right.

I don't understand why `lxml` affects the excel response of django with uwsgi

How can I get the right excel file response with `uwsgi` in this situation?

Thanks.

python version:  `Python 3.6.8`

package list:

```
asgiref==3.2.7
Django==3.0.6
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
jdcal==1.4.1
lxml==4.5.1
mysqlclient==1.4.6
numpy==1.18.4
openpyxl==3.0.3
pandas==1.0.3
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
uWSGI==2.0.18
xlrd==1.2.0
```

- Updated different condition detail

```
environ condition             excel_file(if excel file can be opened)

gunicorn + lxml  + django                      yes

gunicorn + django                              yes

django runserver + lxml                        yes

django runserver                               yes

uwsgi + lxml  + django                         no

uwsgi + django                                 yes
```

Comment: This works for me, with uwsgi, gunicorn and django runserver. If you still have this problem, it would help if you posted the uwsgi logs.

Comment: @Ronald Thanks sir for replying my question,. After my attemps, I found that `lxml` has some effects on generating excel file . I mean if  there is no `lxml` package installed in my env, I could get the right format excel file. But I can't understand why this happended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer as to what exactly caused the error you had, but if your question is why the presence of lxml is affecting your output, then it is because openpyxl uses `lxml` when it is installed, but the standard library's `xml` package when it is not installed.

From the openpyxl [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/index.html?highlight=lxml):

> There is support for the popular lxml library which will be used if it is installed. This is particular useful when creating large files.

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/8953233f5af287d9cdf3dae34e437e76bea5bd59/openpyxl/cell/_writer.py?at=default#lines-103) is where you can see in the openpyxl source that it checks whether `lxml` is installed or not before deciding which function to call.

Comment: Thanks for reply. My confusion is that  only `lxml` + `uwsgi`  + `django`  combination failed to generate a right excel file. And if i uninstall `lxml` in my env it works.